# mthread and multiple header files

Tags: threads

I'm using mthreads (https://github.com/jlamothe/mthread) for my arduino. But now as the project is getting bigger, it would make sense to break it up in several files.

I successfully outsourced already a part which is not threaded. But somehow I cannot make up my mind how to use mthread in conjunction with several header files.

here is what I got:

main: call header:

```
#include "tcan.h"
```

tcan.h:

```
#ifndef tcan_h
#define tcan_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class tcan : public Thread {
  public: tcan();
  protected: bool loop();
  private:
};
#endif
```

tcan.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "tcan.h"
#include <mcp_can.h>

bool tcan::loop() {
  // lala
  return true;
}
```

but I get an error when compiling:

> tcan.h:6:28: error: expected class-name before '{' token  class tcan :
>   public Thread {

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check for circular #includes... The error can be caused by including Arduino.h twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error is due to that the compiler does not know what Thread is.

> tcan.h:6:28: error: expected class-name before '{' token class tcan : public Thread {

The issue is that the header file is not complete. **A good practice is to include all header files that are needed to read the header file.** As *Thread* is defined in *mthread.h* the *tcan.h* file should be:

```
#ifndef tcan_h
#define tcan_h

#include <mthread.h>

class tcan : public Thread {
public: tcan();
protected: bool loop();
private:
};
#endif
```

Cheers!

Comment: that was the right hint "Assuming that Thread is defined in mcp_can.h".

Of course I need to include "<mthread.h>". Thanks for the hint! It's working now.

Comment: Great! I will update the answer with the correct include.